# How to open folder picker dialog in vscode with a pre-selected file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

`vscode.window.showOpenDialog` accepts a `defaultUri` option, but it only seems to apply at the folder level.

Anyone knows how can I open a dialog where a file is already pre-selected for the user if the file exists?

Im'currently doing this:

```
const d = path.join(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath, 'okteto.yml');
return vscode.window.showOpenDialog({
        defaultUri: d,
        openLabel: label,
        canSelectMany: false,
        canSelectFiles: true,
        canSelectFolders: false,
        filters: {
            'Okteto Manifest': ['yml', 'yaml']
        }
    });
```

When the dialog is opened, I'd like the `okteto.yml` file to be pre-selected if it exists. With the code above, the folder is selected, but not the specific file I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
const d = path.join(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri.fsPath, 'okteto.yml');
```

to

```
const d = vscode.Uri.joinPath(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri, 'okteto.yml');
```

`defaultUri` takes a `Uri` so `vscode.Uri.joinPath()` is a good choice here.